# If I restart xinetd service , does it impact the currently active FTP connections?

Tags: linux, ftp, service, xinetd, pureftpd

In my Linux system FTP server is running from xinetd . I want to make a configuration change inside the **/etc/xinetd.d/** directory for the FTP server launch , with respect to the arguments passed to the FTP server .

So for this change do I have to restart the xinetd service ?

Also if I restart the xinetd service ,does it make any issues to the currently active FTP connections to the server ?

Answer (score 1):

Make the changes you want to your configuration file and then do a graceful restart. This will force the process to reread it's configuration, while still serving active and established connections. After the reload, all new sessions will be served with the updated configuration.

To do a graceful restart type: `sudo killall -HUP xinetd` (this will affect all xinetd instances).

A normal restart will affect all active sessions and will interrupt them.